# Workflow Suspended with This Error

Tags: workflow, permissions, workflow-manager

We have a 2013 workflow that was created and published by a site collection administrator, it starts a 2010 workflow. I have given the "Everyone" Group as well as individual accounts full control on all lists including workflow history, workflow tasks list, and the list the workflow runs on. Here is the error.

```
RequestorId: 8a4b1a3d-ea28-b107-0000-000000000000. 
Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. 
Exception details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 401
 {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":
["0"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":
["23"],"SPRequestGuid":["8a4b1a3d-ea28-b107-8030-c051db94d256"],"request-id":
["8a4b1a3d-ea28-b107-8030-c051db94d256"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":
["SAMEORIGIN"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4569"],
"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1; RequireReadOnly"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0, private"],"Date":["Thu, 18 Jun 2015 15:33:57 GMT"],"Server":["Microsoft-IIS\/8.5"],
"WWW-Authenticate":["NTLM"],"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]} 
at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute
(CodeActivityContext context) at
 System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, 
ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at 
System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, 
BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
```

The only people so far from testing who can run the workflow successfully are the Site collection administrators, and the Site collection Owners. The site where the workflow is ran, everyone has Read Permissions, but the lists have broken inheritance, where Everyone and individual accounts were made full control for testing. I still receive this error.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If the workflow is sending an email, check to see if the email is being sent to a group. If the group settings do not allow everyone to view membership, you will get a suspended workflow.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the Group as a contributor on the site level. This is unacceptable, does anyone know of another solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to elevate Workflow permissions in SharePoint 2013 by doing the following :

- Allow workflow to use app permissions.
- Grant full control permission to a workflow.
- Develop the workflow to wrap actions inside an App Step using SharePoint Designer.

> For more details about How to apply the above steps, please check [elevate Workflow permissions in SharePoint 2013](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sharepoint-workflow-suspended-unauthorized/)